# How to skip first few lines from file in Python until line with required prefix is found, without writing a comparison function

Tags: python, string, file

I need to read lines from the text file like this:

```
junk_line_1 
junk_line_2
junk_line_3
real data starts here
```

so I need to skip the lines until the line starting with 'real data' is found.

The solution I have is:

```
import itertools

def has_prefix(line):
  return not line.startswith('real data')

def read_file(f):
  lines=[]
  for line in itertools.dropwhile(has_prefix, f):
    lines.append(line.rstrip())
  return lines
```

I do not like the need to write this 'has_prefix' function, though. For one thing, it looks a bit ugly, for another, I can use it with only one prefix. The ideal solution I would like to get is like this (not syntactically correct) :

```
import itertools

def read_file(f, prefix):
  lines=[]
  for line in itertools.dropwhile(not line.startswith(prefix), f) :
    lines.append(line.rstrip())
  return lines
```

I cannot use this, as `line` is not defined until the loop's body is entered. But may be something is possible in reasonably elegant way? At the very least, I would like to be able to pass function `has_prefix` prefix as a parameter, rather then have it hard-coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropwhile` expects a callback as first argument. So you could use `lambda` there. You also had two typos in that same statement (`startswith` and missing colon):

```
for line in itertools.dropwhile(lambda line: not line.startswith(prefix), f):
```

Answer (score 1):

itertools seems like overkill for this situation.  You could use a simple for loop instead:

```
def read_file(f):
  # read all the lines into a list
  lines = f.readlines()

  # loop over each position of the line list
  for i in range(len(lines)):

      # if the line at this position starts with the desired prefix,
      # return this line and all following lines
      if lines[i].startswith(prefix):
          return lines[i:]
```

Comment: Thank you, it is a workable answer, but it requires reading the whole file in the memory. In real problem, I want to start processing content of the file from the 'real data' line, not just return the whole lot.